# invalid operands to binary expression when trying to merge sort on vector

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

Code:

```
template <typename T>
void merge_sort(std::vector<T>& vector)
{
    if (vector.size() < 2)
        return;
    std::vector<T> left, right;
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0) 
            left.push_back(vector[i]);
        else
            right.push_back(vector[i]);
    }
    merge_sort(left);
    merge_sort(right);

    sort(vector,left, right);
}

template<typename T>
void sort(std::vector<T>& v, std::vector<T>& left, std::vector<T>&     right)
{
    int k = 0;
    while ((left.size() != 0) && (right.size() != 0))
        if (left[0] <= right[0])
        {
            v[k++] = left[0];
            left.erase(v.begin());
        }
        else
        {
            v[k++] = right[0];
            right.erase(v.begin());
        }
    while (left.size() != 0)
    {

        v[k++] = left[0];
        left.erase(v.begin());
    }
    while (right.size() !=0)
    {
        v[k++] = right[0];
        right.erase(v.begin());
    }
}
```

Here is the full error message:

```
clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++1y -Wall -pedantic -g -O3 src/main.cpp  -o project1.out
In file included from src/main.cpp:11:
In file included from src/reporting.hpp:10:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/algorithm:62:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_algo.h:1964:22: error: invalid operands to
      binary expression ('std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' and 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >')
                std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
                      ~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_algo.h:4729:12: note: in instantiation of
      function template specialization 'std::__sort<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >,
      __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >' requested here
      std::__sort(__first, __last, __gnu_cxx::__ops::__iter_comp_iter(__comp));
       ^
src/sorting.hpp:83:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::sort<std::vector<int,
      std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >' requested here
    sort(vector,left, right);
    ^
src/main.cpp:21:64: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'merge_sort<int>' requested here
    std::vector<sorter_t<int>> sorters = {insertion_sort<int>, merge_sort<int>, hybrid_sort<int>};
                                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_bvector.h:208:3: note: candidate function
      not viable: no known conversion from 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' to 'const std::_Bit_iterator_base' for
      1st argument
  operator-(const _Bit_iterator_base& __x, const _Bit_iterator_base& __y)
  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:328:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'reverse_iterator' against 'vector'
    operator-(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:380:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'reverse_iterator' against 'vector'
    operator-(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:911:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match '__normal_iterator' against 'vector'
    operator-(const __normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& __lhs,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:923:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match '__normal_iterator' against 'vector'
    operator-(const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __lhs,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:1138:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'move_iterator' against 'vector'
    operator-(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:1145:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'move_iterator' against 'vector'
    operator-(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
    ^
In file included from src/main.cpp:11:
In file included from src/reporting.hpp:10:
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/algorithm:62:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_algo.h:1878:18: error: invalid operands to
      binary expression ('std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' and 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >')
      if (__last - __first > int(_S_threshold))
      ~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_algo.h:1966:9: note: in instantiation of
      function template specialization 'std::__final_insertion_sort<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >,
      __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >' requested here
      std::__final_insertion_sort(__first, __last, __comp);
           ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_algo.h:4729:12: note: in instantiation of
      function template specialization 'std::__sort<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >,
      __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > >' requested here
      std::__sort(__first, __last, __gnu_cxx::__ops::__iter_comp_iter(__comp));
       ^
src/sorting.hpp:83:2: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::sort<std::vector<int,
      std::allocator<int> >, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >' requested here
    sort(vector,left, right);
    ^
src/main.cpp:21:64: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'merge_sort<int>' requested here
    std::vector<sorter_t<int>> sorters = {insertion_sort<int>, merge_sort<int>, hybrid_sort<int>};
                                   ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_bvector.h:208:3: note: candidate function
      not viable: no known conversion from 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >' to 'const std::_Bit_iterator_base' for
      1st argument
  operator-(const _Bit_iterator_base& __x, const _Bit_iterator_base& __y)
  ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:328:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'reverse_iterator' against 'vector'
    operator-(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:380:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'reverse_iterator' against 'vector'
    operator-(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:911:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match '__normal_iterator' against 'vector'
    operator-(const __normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& __lhs,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:923:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match '__normal_iterator' against 'vector'
    operator-(const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __lhs,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:1138:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'move_iterator' against 'vector'
    operator-(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5.3.1/../../../../include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_iterator.h:1145:5: note: candidate template
      ignored: could not match 'move_iterator' against 'vector'
    operator-(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

Comment: What `T` are you passing in?

Comment: Even if you find and fix the compilation error, the shown code will not work and will likely result in an immediate crash due to undefined behavior. `erase()` requires an iterator from the same container, not some other completely unrelated container. Whatever this is trying to do, it's doing it wrong.

Comment: suppose i change it to r.begin(),  and l.begin() instead of using v.begin for everything......im passing integers

Comment: Any rogue `using namespace std;` in your code? You seem to accidentally call some standard library function. (Indicated by the double underscores in the error message.) Anyways, [mcve] please.

Comment: no, the only using i could find is with some code my proffessor wrote to generate random vectors...."using generator = decltype(&generate_random);"

Comment: @MattMclaughlin I see. ADL dragged it in then. This would probably be a good question if it hat a [mcve].

Comment: My apolagies, I will update the code so, but how should i do it if its spread accross 3 files?

Comment: @MattMclaughlin The link in my comments provides help on how to reduce a longer program to a MCVE.

Comment: Add line breaks from your original error mesage.  And add as much of your code as neccessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: "My apolagies, I will update the code so, but how should i do it if its spread accross 3 files? " - remove everything which is not neccessary to reproduce the error.  Almost certainly, you will be left with not more than 10-30 lines of code totally.  Then merge your three files to one (which would still reproduce the error), and send it.

Comment: Please replace `sort` by `Merge` or `merge_sorted_vectors` everywhere in your code.  Probably, your first error will go away.

Comment: that did it, thank you user31264

Answer (score 1):

Your code breaks because you are using erase incorrecrly: you need to pass the begin() of the vector being erased.

However, using erase is a bad idea to begin with, because it makes your sort asymptotically slower by a factor of N. You should make a pair of iterators, one for left and the other one for right, and move them as you progress through your arrays. This will keep merge an O(n) operation, instead of O (n^2) in your current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
 left.erase(v.begin());
```

Never ever do this.  `foo.erase` requires a member of `foo`.

Even if you wrote `left.erase(left.begin());`, this would still be a terrible coding, and I mean terrible.  Unless you erase last element, or one very close to the end, erasing a vector element is slow like hell. It takes O(N) steps.  So don't `erase` (or `insert`, for that matter) vector elements, unless you are absolutely sure it is a right thing to do.

The whole point of the merge sort is to do sorting in O(N log N) steps.  By using erase, you make it O(N**2*log N) steps.

And don't ever call your function "sort", because there is a sort function already in STL. It is confusing.  Calling a global (not member) function "sort", "exp", "abs", etc. is really a bad idea.  With member functions, it is slightly better. Calling your function "sort" is as if I would change my name to Matt Mclaugin, and went to live near you.

Newbies also like to call a vector "list".  I'll never understand why.

```
This is the some of the error message....

error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::vector >' and 'std::vector >') std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
```

You should copy the error message(s) exactly as they were, not "some of the error message".

Besides, your code is not complete.  You should present enough of your code so that we'll be able to reproduce your error.